# Magento duplicate product with leaving out specific attributes

Tags: magento, attributes, duplicates, product

I would like to be able to Duplicate a product using the default Magento Duplicate option, but leave out several attributes that need to be blank so that the user is forced to change them before saving. **Example:** after duplicating, my attribute *Table-Depth* is always different, and if not left blank could go un-noticed for the user to input proper new value.

Answer (score 0):

You could create an observer for `catalog_model_product_duplicate`

Take a look at [Change Magento default status for duplicated products](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12677971/change-magento-default-status-for-duplicated-products)

Then in your observer, set the fields value to NULL, '' or whatever their default value are.

eg.

```
class MagePal_ResetDuplicateProductValues_Model_Observer 
{

   public function productDuplicate(Varien_Event_Observer  $observer)
   {
      $newProduct = $observer->getEvent()->getNewProduct();
      $newProduct->setTableDepth('');
      ...
```